# SWT: Change style of a Shell at runtime

Tags: java, swt

Is there a way to change the style of a Shell at runtime?

I would like to have a shell not resizable but capable to fill, with its content, the whole screen, when it's in fullscreen. Is there a way to accomplish that?

In other words, when a Shell is not resizable and it has for example a Background Image I get this in full screen :
[image]

On the other hand when the Shell is resizable and I go in full screen I get this:
[image]

So would like to obtain the second effect but with a not resizable Shell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question -- what would be the problem with removing RESIZE from SHELL_TRIM (keeping MIN, MAX, TITLE and CLOSE), i.e. ``new Shell(SHELL_TRIM & ~RESIZE);``

Comment: Hi Stefan , If you mean this: "Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM & ~SWT.RESIZE);" This is resizable at least on Mac (just tried).
That is equivalent to this: "Shell shell = new Shell(display,
    SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN | SWT.MAX);"

Comment: If for example you use this: "Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.TITLE | SWT.CLOSE & ~SWT.RESIZE);" this is not resizable, but when you go on full screen, the content of the Shell is not spread for all the screen

Comment: Same problem here: "Shell shell = new Shell(display,
    SWT.TITLE | SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MIN & ~SWT.RESIZE);" , adding SWT.MAX it starts to be resizable again...

Comment: Have you considered listening to the maximize event and then setting the size of the frame to the full screen size programatically?

Comment: Hi @StefanHaustein following your suggestion I was able to accomplish it ;) Thank you, I'm going to reply to the post with the explanation... Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Stefan's comment, I was able to do it listening to the resize event and checking the fullscreen flag, resizing appropriately the shell's size to the monitor size when it's in full screen and to normal size when is not. Here the code that does the trick:

```
shell.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
                if (shell.getFullScreen()) {
                    Rectangle r = getMonitorSize(shell);
                    shell.setSize(r.width, r.height);
                    shell.redraw();
                } else {
                    shell.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
                    shell.redraw();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I need to disable the resizing functionality for wizard window. I am creating a shell like this.

final Shell shell = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();

I need to remove the resize functionality so I need to get the style of shell but shell.getStyle() is not available, where I need to perform this 
( & ~RESIZE).

Comment: As far as I remember you cannot disable resize once you have created the shell, but you can use my method to avoid the resizing... listening to that event... copy past the portion of code in my accepted answer...